# Como comparar array com string?

Tags: php

O array `$buscaMov[9]`, contém a palavra "Interno", mas o `if` só me retorna falso, no caso, vai sempre parar ao `else`. Deveria cadastrar na tabela compras, mas só cadastra na vendas.

```
if ($buscaMov[9] == "Interno"){

    $movInterno = mysql_query("INSERT INTO compras(descComp,precoComp,dataComp,setorComp) "
                            . "VALUES ($buscaMov[1],$buscaMov[7],$buscaMov[2],$buscaMov[8])");

}else{

    $movExterno = mysql_query("INSERT INTO vendas(setorVend,precoVend,formPagVend,dataVend,descVend)"
                           . " VALUES ('$buscaMov[8]','$buscaMov[7]','x-x-x','$buscaMov[2]','$buscaMov[1]')");

}
```

Comment: Tem certeza que `$buscaMov[9]` contém mesmo "Interno"? Antes do `if` coloca um `var_dump($buscaMov);` e posta o resultado só pra garantir...

Comment: Tem sim, olha ai:  [9]=> string(7) "Interno"

Comment: Faça ``$teste = $buscaMov[9] == "Interno"; var_dump($teste);``

Comment: Em tese é pra funcionar assim, veja um exemplo no [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/3XyKCR).

Comment: Vem de um csv esses valores? poderia colocar onde o array é inicializado?

Comment: O if ta funcionando, oque não ta é o primeiro insert, caso seja igual a interno ...

Comment: Strings(textos) devem estar entre aspas simples. Ué voltou a funcionar do nada? rs

Comment: Exato @rray, o problema era esse mesmo

Comment: Qual era o problema? alterei minha resposta, veja se resolve o problema.

Comment: O problema eram as aspas simples faltando no primeiro insert ''

Answer (score 1):

Certifique que a string dentro `$buscaMov` seja a mesa da comparação, defina um padrão ex, usar minusculas e também remova os espaços no inicio e fim da string com o `trim()`

Mude: para:

```
if (trim(strtolower($buscaMov[9])) == "interno"){
```

Para facilitar a identificação do erro use a função `mysql_error()`.

```
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO compras(descComp,precoComp,dataComp,setorComp) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')",
                $buscaMov[1],$buscaMov[7],$buscaMov[2],$buscaMov[8]);
$movInterno = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Não me parece ser esse o problema visto que as strings são iguais pelo que diz o AP.

Comment: +1 Mas se as strings baterem, em tese é pra funcionar do jeito que está né: https://ideone.com/3XyKCR